# AngularJS prevent blur until ngDialog confirmed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of input fields that look like this:

```
<span style="float:left;"><input type="number" ng-model="discount.amount" price-check /></span>
```

I want to prevent the user from getting out of the input field if the price they entered is too low. They have to fill in a small form before they can exit the field. I used to do this with jquery by setting focus back on the element (which I think is default behavior of ngDialog) if the user clicked cancel on the form, otherwise I just let the default event happen if the form had been confirmed.

I have been trying to convert this to angularjs but I am having issues with the blur event and ngDialog. The normal usage will be that the user fills in the input and then presses TAB to get to the next one. The issue is that pressing TAB calls the blur event which opens the dialog, but the next input (behind the dialog) gains focus at the same time, so as soon as I click on the dialog, another dialog pops up because the second input called its blur event.
I need to prevent the blur event from moving to the next input when the dialog is already open from a previous input. I tried using event.preventDefault() and stopPropagation() but they didn't seem to work.

Here is my directive

```
customerPricingModule.directive('priceCheck', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'priceCheckController',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        element.on('blur', function (event) {
            //If statement to go here to only open if under a certain price
            ctrl.showDialog(element);

            //when dialog cancelled, focus on the element again
            //Otherwise don't do anything
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: On open of the dialog you should give focus to some element inside of the dialog to prevent the background tab clicks from re-creating the dialog. This kind of focus issue is always a beast.

Comment: I think the focus is already on the next input by the time the dialog opens though.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I'm stuck with same issue